# Unresolved Identifier when creating an array in TableViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class FishTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//MARK: Properties 

var fish = [Fish]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //load fish example cell
    loadSampleFish();
}

func loadSampleFish(){

    let grouperPhoto = UIImage(named: "blackgrouper");
    let exampleFish = Fish(name: "Black Grouper", photo: grouperPhoto);
    fish += [exampleFish];
}
```

Unresolved identifier on "var fish = Fish" and "let exampleFish = Fish(name: "Black Grouper", photo: grouperPhoto);"

Comment: That means Xcode doesn't know what 'Fish' is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Fish class is defined with the same target as your tableviewcontroller. Look under "target membership" in File Inspector.